# CSS selector to apply CSS if class is on element

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller, sass

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="date-question col-md-5">
    <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col">
            <p class="name"></p> 
         </div>
         <div class="col-5 px-2">
            <p class="name"></p>  
         </div>
         <div class="col">
            <p class="name"></p>
         </div>
         <span class="summary-validation field-validation-error">Invalid name.</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

How do I apply CSS to elements with the class `name` if `field-validaiton-error` is exists?

I want to make the `<p>` elements have a red background only if `field-validation-error` which is the summary validation message appears. The class is added to the validation summary by MVC

Comment: you can learn about css classes here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.php

Comment: @Jefferson Thanks for the link but I don't think w3schools covers complicated CSS selectors like this

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't quite understand the question, my bad. I think then you might be looking for something like this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.php or this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.php . But if this doesn't work then you might not want to solve it with css at all, a javascript method might be more appropriate for this kind of task.

Comment: But to be fair, if the field-validation-error was at the top instead of the bottom then this solution `.field-validation-error ~ div p {color: red;}` would work

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to select elements that is not your sibling or child, so the only way I can think of is starting from the parent or adjacent container of `field-validation-error`.

### Check if `d-flex` contains child:

You can use `:has` to check if `d-flex` has any child element with class `field-validation-error`: (Change .name to p.name depending on your needs.)

```css
.d-flex:has( > .field-validation-error) .name{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="date-question col-md-5">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col">
          <p class="name">13</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 px-2">
          <p class="name">456</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p class="name">123</p>
        </div>
        <span class="summary-validation field-validation-error"
        >Invalid name.</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="date-question col-md-5">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col">
          <p class="name">13</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 px-2">
          <p class="name">456</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p class="name">123</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

### Check if `d-flex>div` contains sibling:

You can use `:has` to check if `d-flex>div` has any [subsequence sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator)(~) with class `field-validation-error`: (Note that this will only work if all `name` precedes `field-validation-error`)

```css
.d-flex>div:has(~ .field-validation-error) .name {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="date-question col-md-5">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="col">
      <p class="name">13</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 px-2">
      <p class="name">456</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p class="name">123</p>
    </div>
    <span class="summary-validation field-validation-error">Invalid name.</span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="date-question col-md-5">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="col">
      <p class="name">13</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 px-2">
      <p class="name">456</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p class="name">123</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the `.d-flex:has( > .field-validation-error) .name{}` selector. Very clear. I would personally add `( > span.summary-validation.field-validation-error)` to narrow it down a bit further just in case I reuse that `field-validation-error` class again within another `.d-flex`  but that's me. This is a good solution.